# How to return the max value in list in a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a dictionary with values that are a list:

```
dict1 = {'d1': [1, 1, 2], 'd11': [1, 1, 4, 1], 'd16': [1, 1, 5]}
```

I'm trying to change the dictionary so that list return the max value as an integer.
This what I want:

```
dict1 = {'d1': 2, 'd11': 4, 'd16': 5}
```

I've tried using max() but it's not really working for me.

Comment: _tried using max() but it's not really working for me_ Show us the code you tried.  Otherwise we can't say what you did wrong.

Comment: `dict = {key:max(value) for key, value in dict.items()}`

Comment: Iterate over the keys and values of your dictionary, find the max of each value, assign that back to `dict[key]`.

Comment: note that you shouldn't name your variable 'dict' since that overwrites the build in `dict()` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def max_in_dict(list_dictionary):
    return {key: max(list_dictionary[key]) for key in list_dictionary.keys()}
```

This should do.